# NetLogo Battle Simulation: Placing soldiers in between specific coordinates?

Tags: netlogo

I'm new to NetLogo and I'm unsure of how to place 300 spartans in a narrow row. Let's say an area of 2x5 patches, turtles overlapping one another. I have tried using sprout, this achieved the specific coordinate requirements but the turtles are only one per patch.. Here is some code I have.

```
    ask patches with [pxcor > 0 and pycor > -2 and pycor < 2]
    [ sprout 1 [ set color red ] ]

 or

    to setup-spartans
    create-spartans 300
    set-default-shape turtles "person"

    ask spartans
   [ setxy random-xcor -3  ;; makes only a single row and goes across entire screen  
                           ;; (I need it to be in a specific area)
     set heading 180
     set color red ]

    end
```

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this?

```
create-spartans 300 [
  set xcor -2 + random-float 5
  set ycor -1 + random-float 2
]
```